# TileMill exports too big mbtile file

Tags: openstreetmap, tilemill, mbtiles

I'am trying to export mbtile file from TileMill to use it in my map server. But file is too huge, 17th level will cost 100+GB only for my country. However, i found free mbtile from [openmaptiles.org](https://openmaptiles.org/) with only 1GB size for the same are. 
My question is: How openmaptiles.org reduced 100GB mbtile to 1GB? 
*I don't want to use 1gb file because they have watermarks all over the map*

Comment: The best way to support deep zoom levels is to use vector tiles.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that openmaptiles.org provides only 14 zoom levels and can be over zoomed till 18. Overall, 14 layers are >1gb size